# How to grant a execute permission on stored procedure for an user(Already dbo) to run a SSRS report

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I am newbie. 
I already have a dbo permission. I have written a stored procedure to insert records into certain table, and have designed SSRS report(UI to add records) that executes this stored procedure.
5 of us have the dbo permission, how can I grant a 'execute' permission to only 1 user(Me) out of 5 users (already with dbo permissions)? 
i.e on deploying the SSRS report(which in turn executes the stored procedure) on intranet i want that to be executed only by only 1 user(Me).
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There's a few dependencies, and the assumption I've made is that you're using windows and you have the ability to set Datasources on the box you are deploying to?

that being the case -  ensure set up the datasource to run with the windows credentials of the person running the report?
[image]

Once you've got that you can pass the UserID as a parameter to your Stored Procedure

```
User!UserID
```

Then you can test whether its your user in the SP.

```
 if SYSTEM_USER = @username
      Insert into xxx...
```

Answer (score 0):

Old thread, but I deal with this daily and maybe others who come looking for this in the future. I will assume your server deployment folder you have perms to create and deploy a data source. Your data source you deploy could use your windows login. However, usually when an SSRS is deployed, the grant execute is set to the group at the bottom of the stored proc. You could just have your windows sys admin add you to a new group/service account, which would be scalable in the future if you add more people.

GO

grant execute on [dbo].[proc name]  to [some_role]

GO

It all really depends on the size of your organization. A small business may just hack things together to get them working, or in my case a large financial institution will have heavy security in place and we have to adhere to policy, or audit is going to have fun with us. -Nick